# why am I getting different answers with dsolve?

Tags: matlab

I have defined the following ODE

```
syms R1 C1 vc0 Vin
Vc_ode = 'Dvc+vc/(R1*C1)=(Vin)/(R1*C1)';
Vc=dsolve(Vc_ode,'vc(0)=vc0','t');
```

and the solution I receive is

```
Vin - (Vin - vc0)/exp(t/(C1*R1))
```

while solving manually I get

```
 Vin +vc0*exp(-t/(C1*R1))
```

both are correct solutions, but is there a way to reach my desired solution?

Comment: you forgot a minus sign in your solution...

Comment: its a typo...minus t. original syntax was vc0/exponent

Answer (score 0):

I think the *practical answer* would be: No, you cannot let MATLAB reach your desired solution.

When looking at the dsolve input there is no option to specify what the output should look like. It is just a guess but this may be because it is hard to translate your desired style into code.

The only thing that might make a difference is the way you write the input formula but I would suspect it is not going to make much difference.

On the other hand, the *academic answer* would be: Everything is possible, you may need to make your own dsolve function though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the manual solution `vc(t) = Vin +vc0*exp(-t/(C1*R1))` is incorrect. That solutions has `vc(0) = Vin + vc0` which is not equal to `vc0`, so this is why your solutions differ.  There is a theorem that states that a first order linear ODE with a initial condition like `vc(t_0) = ...` has exactly one solution.  I suggest that you carefully go through you steps.